# Merge two lists of data frames

Tags: r, list, merge, lapply

I have two lists of data frames. Each list has 6 data frames. 
The dataframes has the same columns, but in list1 the dataframes has info from 2015 to 2017 and list2 has info of 2018. Like below

List1$A

```
Name Value  Year
AAA  123   2015
BBB  456   2016
CCC  789   2017
AAA  543   2018
```

List2$A

```
Name Value  Year
AAA  543    2018
BBB  248    2018
```

I want to merge the dataframes from both lists. So I want in the end just one list of dataframes with all the info for all years.

Some dataframes from list1 has already info of 2018, so when I merge them with the others I want those 2018 values to be replaced.

Newlist$A

```
Name Value  Year
AAA  123    2015
BBB  456    2016
CCC  789    2017
AAA  543    2018
BBB  248    2018
```

I tried this but didn't work

```
data<- lapply(list1,list2, function (x,y) merge(x,y))
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You could check out rbindlist from the data.table package. You could delete the duplicates after the rbind

Answer (score 0):

It's always helpful to include a sample of data with `dput`, but here's an attempt without the data's confirmation:

```
library(tidyverse)

map2(list1, list2, ~bind_rows(.y, .x) %>% group_by(Name, Year) %>% slice(1))
```

We bind the rows (with `list2` first), then grouping by `Name` and `Year` and taking the first occurrence with `slice`, which should take the first value for any `Name`/`Year` repeated measures from the 2nd data frame.

Comment: How does your code behave if there is a missing entry in list 2? See example data I've created in my answer.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it would just use the entry from group 1

Answer (score 0):

We could first bind everything into a long data frame and remove the entries for `"2018"` that first occur if there's an entry in list 2.

To do this we could `list` the lists and `rbind` them after adding an ID column that later helps to remove the duplicates of year `"2018"` that stem from list 1 with `by`/`ave`, but keep those which don't occur in list 2.

The trick of the latter is to us a `rev(seq_along(x))`.

To demonstrate I have created sample data that probably resembles your data.

```
# list the lists
L <- list(L1=L1, L2=L2)

# add id column to sublists
L <- lapply(seq(L), function(x) 
  Map(`[<-`, L[[x]], "list", value=substr(names(L)[x], 2, 2)))

# rbind lists to long data frame
d <- do.call(rbind, unlist(L, recursive=FALSE))

# remove 2018 duplicates of list L1, keep if no 2018 in list L2
do.call(rbind, by(d, d$name, function(y) {
  i <- cbind(y, id=ave(y$year, y$year, FUN=function(z) rev(seq_along(z))))
  i[!i$id == 2, ]
  }))
```

***Result***

```
#        name value year list id
# A.A.1     A   998 2015    1  1
# A.A.4     A   456 2016    1  1
# A.A.7     A   312 2017    1  1
# A.A.13    A   478 2018    2  1
# B.A.2     B  1592 2015    1  1
# B.A.5     B  1072 2016    1  1
# B.A.8     B   673 2017    1  1
# B.A.21    B   445 2018    2  1
# C.A.3     C   957 2015    1  1
# C.A.6     C   199 2016    1  1
# C.A.9     C  2165 2017    1  1
# C.A.31    C   342 2018    2  1
# D.B.1     D   877 2015    1  1
# D.B.4     D   876 2016    1  1
# D.B.7     D   482 2017    1  1
# D.B.13    D  1077 2018    2  1
# E.B.2     E   370 2015    1  1
# E.B.5     E  1475 2016    1  1
# E.B.8     E   768 2017    1  1
# E.B.11    E   385 2018    1  1  <- this stems from list 1!
# F.B.3     F   421 2015    1  1
# F.B.6     F   930 2016    1  1
# F.B.9     F  1105 2017    1  1
# F.B.31    F  1836 2018    2  1
```

***Data***

```
l1 <- list(A = structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(1371, 565, 363, 633, 404, 106, 1512, 95, 2018, 
    63, 1305, 2287), year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 
    2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L)), B = structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(1389, 279, 133, 636, 284, 2656, 2440, 1320, 307, 
    1781, 172, 1215), year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 
    2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L)))

L2 <- list(A = structure(list(name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), value = c(1895, 430, 257), year = c(2018, 
2018, 2018)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)), 
    B = structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 3L), .Label = c("D", 
    "E", "F"), class = "factor"), value = c(1763, 640), year = c(2018, 
    2018)), row.names = c(1L, 3L), class = "data.frame"))

L2$B <- L2$B[-2, ]  # remove intentionally value
```